# The complex version of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

I can't prove the complex version of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.
$$ f(x) \in \mathbf{C} \\
     a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos nx \, dx, \quad
     b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \sin nx \, dx \\
     \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} {f(x)}^2 dx = \frac{a_0^2}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 + b_n^2) $$
When f(x) is real, the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0,\quad \lim_{n \to \infty}b_n=0$$
is obvious.
When f(x) is complex, $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s are also complex.
Is there a possibility
that the LHS converges,
$a_n$'s and $b_n$'s of large $n$'s don't limit to zero when $m \to \infty$,
and $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s of large $n$'s are cancelling?
Can we exclude such a possibility?

Comment: you meant $\frac{|a_0|^2}{2} + \sum_n |a_n|^2+|b_n|^2$ and you should look at the usual form for the Fourier series $f(x) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n x}$, $c_n =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-i  n x}dx$, $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 dx =2 \pi  \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty |c_n|^2$

Comment: $f=g+ih$ where $g$ and $h$ are real...

Comment: @user1952009: Now I understand $\lim_{n \to \infty}c_n =0$. In the complex version, $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s are not real. So $|c_n|^2 =\frac{1}{4}(Rea_n + Imb_n)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(Ima_n - Reb_n)^2$, and we get $\lim_{n \to \infty}(Rea_n + Imb_n) \to 0, \lim_{n \to \infty}(Ima_n - Reb_n) \to 0$. Generally $\lim_{n \to \infty}(Rea_n) \not= 0$ and so on.